# Laplace integration after the first term

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm trying to evaluate $$\int_0^1e^{nh(s)}ds$$
using the Laplace method, where $h$'s maximum is reached $h(0)=0$, and $h'(0) = 0$, $h''(0) < 0$.

The Maclaurin expansion for $h$ gives $h(s) = \frac 12h''(0)s^2+O(s^3)$ and so the integral becomes (if I'm not mistaken) $$\int_0^1exp\left(n(\frac 12 h''(0)s^2+O(s^3)\right)ds = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{-2nh''(0)}}+O\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$$

This is as far as I've gone using the Laplace method. My question is, can the approximation be improved? A method I've seen goes something like this:

change variables $\tau = h(s)$ (or possibly $-\tau^2 = h(s)$) to have $$\int_0^{h(1)}e^{n\tau}\frac{ds}{d\tau}d\tau$$
and expand $\frac{ds}{d\tau}=-\frac{1}{h'(s)}$ around $0$. This seems to work, but not in my case where $h'(0) = 0$, which I just can't work around.

I've also had the idea of trying to expand $h(s)$ further, but I'm not sure this is allowed, or if it can help in these circumstances.

I'd love to hear your thoughts. Thanks!

Comment: The substitution $t=h(s)$ does work; however, the integral become an *improper* integral. Note that the improper integral $\Gamma(1+\alpha)=\int_0^\infty e^{-q}q^\alpha dq$ converges even when $-1<\alpha<0$.

Comment: Bibliography: de Bruijn's *Asymptotic methods in analysis*

Comment: My recollection of asymptotic expansions of this kind is that adding more terms is allowable, but not necessarily helpful.  By this, I mean that for any finite values $n$, a sequence of higher and higher order approximations will actually diverge at the point $n$.  Usually you just live with the fact that $n$ is large and that the major contribution to the integral comes from the stationary point where $h'=0$.  If you want to go a step further, you find an error bound on your approximation as a function of $n$.

Comment: If you're interested in numerical evaluation of such integrals, there are efficient quadratures.  You can check out the works of Iserles  on quadrature, who seems to be the preeminent expert on the numerical aspects of oscillatory integrals (http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/ai/Publications/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a better approximation for the integral, simply use the next terms in the Maclurin expansion of $h$.  For example,

$$h(s) = \frac12 h''(0) s^2 + \frac16 h'''(0) s^3 + O\left(s^4\right)$$

Now, recall that, when we derived the approximation for the $s^2$ term, we assumed that the integral was dominated by the integrand's value in the interval $[0,s_0]$, where $n s_0^2 = O(1)$, or $s_0 = O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)$.  Then, consider the next term in the approximation to $h$, $n s^3$.  By the previous argument, this term will be of the order of $n s_0^2 s_0 = O\left(n^{-1/2}\right)$ and therefore will be small as $n \to \infty$.  In that case, we may Taylor expand the exponential from this term on; to wit:

$$\int_0^1 ds\, e^{n h(s)} \sim \int_0^{\infty} ds\, e^{-n (|h''(0)/2| s^2} \left [ 1+ \frac16 n h'''(0) s^3\right]\quad (n \to \infty)$$

The error in this approximation is $ O\left (n^{-3/2}\right)$.  I hope that you see how to evaluate this integral, as well as add additional terms.